# jQuery nextAll add extra html

Tags: php, jquery

After playing for hours yesterday, thought of seeking your help. Not sure whether this kind of question has been asked before, but couldn't find any help out there.

I have 4 dependent drop downs and it grabs data from a `sql` database on drop-down `change`. On `change`, jQuery passes it's ID to a php file and grabs its drop-down data. it uses `next` and `nextAll` to update the dependent drop-downs.

**My Question**

When I put a div around the drop-downs, they don't load data anymore. I tried change `.update` to `div .update` and 100 other ways, but none of them worked.

**My Code**

```
var formObject = {
    run : function(obj) {
        if (obj.val() === '') {
            obj.nextAll('.update').html('<option value="">----</option>').attr('disabled', true);
        } else {
            var id = obj.attr('id');
            var v = obj.val();
            jQuery.getJSON('/pfi/mod/update.php', { id : id, value : v }, function(data) {
                if (!data.error) {
                    obj.next('.update').html(data.list).removeAttr('disabled');
                    $('.findCar, .clearAll').fadeOut();  // hide Car button if more data available

                } else {
                    obj.nextAll('.update').html('<option value="">----</option>').attr('disabled', true);
                    $('.findCar, .clearAll').fadeIn();  // show Car button

                }
            });
        }
    }
};
$(function() {

    $('.update').live('change', function() {
        formObject.run($(this));
        $getCarInfoID = $(".update:not(:disabled)").last().val();
    });

});
```

**HTML dropdowns**

```
    <form action="" id="pfilterForm" method="post">
    <div>
    <select name="brand" id="brand" class="update">
        <option value="">Select one</option>
        <?php if (!empty($list)) { ?>
            <?php foreach($list as $row) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
    </div><div>

    <select name="make" id="make" class="update"
        disabled="disabled">
        <option value="">----</option>
    </select>
    </div><div>
  <select name="series" id="series" class="update"
        disabled="disabled">
        <option value="">----</option>
    </select>
    </div><div>
    <select name="model" id="model" class="update"
        disabled="disabled">
        <option value="">----</option>
    </select>
    </div> 
    <button name="data" type="button" class="findCar" onclick="getData()" style="display:none;"  >GO</button>
    <button name="data" type="button" class="clearAll" onclick="clearData()" style="display:none;"  >Clear</button>

</form>
```

How can I get this to work with a `div` around the drop-downs? I used this tutorial to get this up to [here](http://www.ssdtutorials.com/tutorials/series/dependable-dropdown.html).

Answer (score 0):

You are relying on `next()` and `nextAll` to select elements. That will rely heavily on the structure of the document.

If you want to target specific elements, you could get them via their ID's as they already have unique ID's.

**Edit:** The fast solution, which still relies heavily on the html (so not really recommended as far as I am concerned...) is to move from your element to its parent and take it from there.

So for example:

```
obj.nextAll('.update')
```

would become something like:

```
obj.parent().nextAll().find('.update')
```

Comment: Is there any way I can add a `div` to `nextAll`?

Comment: @user1889007 All your elements have ID's, you can simply target them directly.

Comment: @user1889007 You would have to address all elements individually, so if you don't want to do that (it would change a lot of code), you could also consider using css to change the display properties of the `input`'s.

Comment: @user1889007 See my edit to use your current javascript with the new html structure.

Comment: hi, thanks for the help. I tried it but didnt work. Im working on different methods like `nextUntil` and `find` combinations and `eq(0)` combinations

Comment: @user1889007 I would not make the code dependant on the html structure, just use the ID's.

Comment: Thanks. I believe you. But with my limited jQuery knowledge its quite tough. Thanks though. :)

Comment: @user1889007 The problem here is that you are addressing multiple elements with your jquery, so it is not that easy to rewrite. Personally I would address every element individually using for example `$("#series")` to address the `series` select.